# Trying to remember the name of a short scifi story about a biology experiment in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the name and author of a science fiction short story I read about 15 years ago in an anthology book.

The story involved a scientific experiment on a spaceship/space station in orbit in the solar system. The experiment consisted of a quickly evolving ecosystem that reproduced evolution. Eventually, the person realizes there is something dangerous going on (don't remember the specifics) and decides to crash the experiment into the sun, if I recall correctly. But as they were passing earth, the experiment "evolves" some sort of spore that gets released from the ship into earth's atmosphere.

Comment: Wow, this sounds ridiculously similar to [_Life_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_(2017_film))

Comment: Interesting... I was going to watch that film but then I saw it wasn't that well reviewed and decided not to

Comment: Btw, this story came back to my mind while I was watching Alien Covenant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "The Engineer and the Executioner" by Brian Stableford.  The "engineer" has created the formidable new life in an asteroid base and the "executioner" comes to kill him and destroy the asteroid. He sends the asteroid into the Sun, but once it crosses Earth's orbit, spores emerge which are blown by the solar wind and will contaminate the Earth.

Comment: Available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v48n06_1975-05).

Comment: Bingo! Thank you!

Comment: And now, after a quick googling, I also know I read this story on a spanish translation of this antology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Science_Fiction:_The_Authors%27_Choice